# Replace a row in python polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to replace a row in a polars DataFrame with a single value:

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = np.zeros(shape=(4, 4))
df = pl.DataFrame(df)
```

For example I want to replace all values in row at index 1 with 1.0 .

I was looking for a straightforward solution in the documentation, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an anti-pattern in Polars to explicitly index. That said, with a `with_row_count` column it is possible to make a new DataFrame with the replaced-by-row values, by using that extra column in a `when/then` expression (and not ultimately `select`ing it in the final result):

```
df.with_row_count().select(
    pl.when(pl.col("row_nr") == 1)
      .then(1)
      .otherwise(pl.col(c))
    .alias(c) for c in df.columns
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i32      ┆ i32      ┆ i32      ┆ i32      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0        ┆ 0        ┆ 0        ┆ 0        │
│ 1        ┆ 1        ┆ 1        ┆ 1        │
│ 0        ┆ 0        ┆ 0        ┆ 0        │
│ 0        ┆ 0        ┆ 0        ┆ 0        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

EDIT: Two improvements:

- There's also a fairly recent `cumcount` that acts as a row count
  expression in the base case, effectively. This keeps the whole query
  lazy.
- `pl.all` can be used to get rid of the generator comprehension above, combined with a `keep_name` to avoid duplicate column errors.

```
df.select(
    pl.when(pl.all().cumcount() == 1)
      .then(1)
      .otherwise(pl.all())
    .keep_name()
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      │
│ 1.0      ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1.0      │
│ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      │
│ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

(Can cast the result to whatever dtype from here)